# Как работать с ControlValueAccessor?

Tags: angular2, angular

Есть форма, содержащая кастомный компонент app-input

[StackBlitx](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bhtrls?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput.component.ts)

```
<form [formGroup]="SignupReactiveForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <app-input  label="email" type="email" formControlName="email">
 </app-input></div>
</form>
```

В неё я хочу передать formControlName="email"
 Мне подсказали про CustomValueAccessor, который я должен реализовать в своем компоненте

```
writeValue(value: any) {
this.formControlName = value;
}
  registerOnChange() { }
  registerOnTouched() { }
```

Я зарегистрировал его

```
{
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => InputComponent),
  multi: true
}
```

Пробую просто через @Input получить значение formControlName, пробую через set и get и ничего не происходит. Читал много и ничего не понял. Как с ним работать? Вот передал я formControlName в компонент и как мне его получить? И как мне его привязать к темплейту компонента?

Answer (score 0):

Сделать следующим образом в вашей компоненте:

```
@Input() formControlName: string;
```

А этот код:

```
writeValue(value: any) {
    this.formControlName = value;
}
```

вызывается тогда, когда вы используете `ngModel`.

```
<app-input  label="email" type="email" [(ngModel)]="value" formControlName="email">
```

но тогда значение `value` в переменную `this.formControlName` вашей компоненты. `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR` позволяет реализовать `ngModel` для кастомной компоненты

Comment: Спасибо. Так у меня используется NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bhtrls-9nkp1p?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput.component.ts

Comment: ```<app-input  label="password" type="password" formControlName="password"></app-input>``` - здесь здесь надо так: ```[formControlName]="password"```